# apply css when element before and after button wrapper using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a code but i don't know why it does not working, even if it's a simple code of
if condition.

```
   $(".btn-superimposed-wrapper").each(function () {
      if (($(this).prev(".wp-block-group")) && ($(this).next(".wp-block-group"))) {
         $(this).css({ "margin-top": "-8rem", "margin-bottom": "-6rem", "text-align": "center" });
      }
   });
```

i also tried with `hasClass()` :

```
 $(".btn-superimposed-wrapper").each(function () {
      if ($(this).prev().hasClass(".wp-block-group") && $(this).next().hasClass(".wp-block-group")) {
         $(this).css({ "margin-top": "-8rem", "margin-bottom": "-6rem", "text-align": "center" });

         console.log("PREV ;",$(this).prev())
         console.log("NEXT ;",$(this).next())
      }
   });
```

i need to add the css style (above) to button when it have a div with class `.wp-block-group` before **AND** after.

But for example if i change the name of the div.`wp-block-group` in the html, it style apply the css as the condition is always true knowing that we have a condition with **AND**, i don't understand !

[image]

Comment: You want to consider using `.hasClass()` with `.prev()` and `.next()` to determine if the style should be applied.

Comment: i made it but now the condition is not true, it does not enter in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
$(".btn-superimposed-wrapper").each(function (i, el) {
  if ($(el).prev().hasClass("wp-block-group") && $(el).next().hasClass("wp-block-group")) {
    $(el).css({
      "margin-top": "-8rem", 
      "margin-bottom": "-6rem", 
      "text-align": "center" 
    });
  }
});
```

This will examine the previous and next elements and if they both have the Class, will return `true`.

Comment: Except for the hadClass . what's the difference between your code and mine please ?

Comment: @MeryemACHEMLAL Your code selects the objects with `$(this).prev(".wp-block-group")`, and this will not return a `true` or `false` as `.hasClass()` will. In regards to your example, you are changing the Class manually, so there is no `event` to trigger a change to the elements or style. So the code I presented will only run on `load` or if its in an Event callback.